# How do I extract HTML img sources with a regular expression?

Tags: regex, asp-classic, vbscript

I need to extract the src element from all image tags in an HTML document.

So, the input is an HTML page and the output would be a list of URL's pointing to images:
ex... http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif

The following is what I came up with so far:

```
<img\s+src=""(http://.*?)
```

This does not work for tags where the src isn't directly after the img tag, for example:

```
<img height="1px" src="spacer.gif">
```

Can someone help complete this regular expression? It's pretty easy, but I thought this may be a faster way to get an answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following regexp snippet should work.

```
<img[^>]+src="([^">]+)"
```

It looks for text that starts with `<img`, followed by one or more characters that are not `>`, then `src="`. It then grabs everything between that point and the next `"` or `>`.

But if at all possible, use a real HTML parser. It's more solid, and will handle edge cases much better.

Comment: It won't work for single quoted tags, and remember that HTML actually doesn't require quotes on attributes unless they contain whitespace.

Comment: also wont work if there is a tag ending with the letters `src`, for example if the image has a `data-src` tag this wont work.

Comment: `<img\s.*?src=(?:'|")([^'">]+)(?:'|")` This looks for a string starting with <img; then one space; then 0 or more of anything; then `src=` single/double quotes (without capture); then capture one or more of anything that isn't a single/double quote or `>`; then a single/double quote (without capture). This one works for single/double quotes and won't pickup other attributes with "src" like `data-src`. http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/kDH

Comment: `<img\s.*?src=(?:'|\")([^'\">]+)(?:'|\").*?\/?>` to capture the entire tag, incase you need to replace it.

Comment: It works in escaped string as well having \n, \r, etc.

Answer (score 11):

You don't want to do that. Correctly parsing HTML is a very complex problem, and regular expressions are not a good tool for that.

See e.g.
[Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-regex)

And here for a good solution:

[How do I programatically inspect a HTML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218535/how-do-i-programatically-inspect-a-html-document)

Answer (score 5):

You could do this pretty easily with Javascript.  An example would be like below:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (i=0; i < images.length; i++)
{
   // get image src
   var currImage = images[i].src;

   // do link creation here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### This works great for me

```
$regexp = '<img[^>]+src=(?:\"|\')\K(.[^">]+?)(?=\"|\')';

if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/", $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {

    if( !empty($matches) ) {

        for ($i=0; $i <= count($matches); $i++)

        {
            $img_src = $matches[$i][0];

            echo $img_src;

        }

    }

}
```