# Haw can we add " in Regex Pattern

Tags: regex

I have a very long string were I would like to match path of an image. for example

```
abc <img src="static/img/about-me.png" title="" alt="". My objective is get string static/img/about-me.png
```

I have a Pattern `@"(?i)(src=)([a-z0-9\\/_-])+\.(png|jpg)"` which should work fine, but it is failing because I need to add single " after src=. I tried many approaches, but unable to resolve it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If it is an option, consider using a parser instead of a regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to extract the path of a `img`, [this solution in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1028370/6373370) should do the trick:

`<img\s.*?src=(?:'|")([^'">]+)(?:'|")`

Test: https://regex101.com/r/ZihKlh/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is not a direct solution, but it worked. I replaced src=" to scr=( and used Regex expression and it work, no issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you didn't put a double quote after your source attribute and you forgot to escape forward slash in your expression.

`(?i)(src=")([a-z0-9\\\/_-])+\.(png|jpg)"` will work.

I suggest you also try out the regex I spun: `<img.*?src="([a-z0-9\\\/_-]+)\.(png|jpg|jpeg)"` this will be a bit faster than yours and will make sure you only pick actual image tags.